# SWT_AWT Double Buffer Issue

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, swt-awt

I have an Eclipse RCP (SWT) Plugin Project and have a view part that has an SWT_AWT Frame with a JTree/JScrollPane/Etc using the following code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
    comp.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(comp);

    try {
        UIManager
                .setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(panel);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode obj = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Test " + i);

        root.add(obj);

        for (int f = 0; f < 100; f++) {
            obj.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Test " + i));
        }
    }

    JTree fileTable = new JTree(root);
    fileTable.setRootVisible(false);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileTable);

    scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setDoubleBuffered(true);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setDoubleBuffered(true);

    panel.add(scrollPane);

    frame.add(scrollPane);
}
```

When I add the code for double buffering; I have it set explicitly on the ScrollBars of the JScrollPanel to see if I could fix the problem.

```
    scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setDoubleBuffered(true);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

I had it set on the scroll panel before this; but either way both things result in the same problem.

[image: Broken Double Buffering]

The issue goes away though when you move the mouse over it; it works as expected. When I switch to other parts (tabs) and go back to this tab, the issue presents itself again. The issue also goes away when I do not set double buffering, but this results in a horrible flickering of the scroll bars.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Tried as redraw after compete composition?

Comment: @rmertins Would you be able to elaborate? I am not 100% sure on what you mean.

Comment: I mean after your panel is shown call redraw on it. To refresh the view. Sorry using my phone not possible to write and verify code

Comment: Yeah I've even repainted it every time `onFocus`; it doesn't seem like it does anything.